# Why disappears mask image after template match?

Tags: opencv

```
Mat img = Mat::zeros(100, 100, CV_8UC3);
Mat pat = Mat::zeros(10, 10, CV_8UC3);
Mat msk = Mat::zeros(10, 10, CV_8UC1);

line(img, Point(10, 10), Point(90, 90), Scalar(255, 255, 255));
line(pat, Point(0, 0), Point(10, 10), Scalar(255, 255, 255));
line(msk, Point(3, 3), Point(7, 7), Scalar(255, 255, 255));

Mat res = Mat();

imwrite("msk-befor.png", msk);
matchTemplate(img, pat, res, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, msk);
imwrite("msk-after.png", msk);

imwrite("img.png", img);
imwrite("pat.png", pat);
```

`msk-befor.png` is okay, It is my intention.

But, `msk-befor.png` is empty and black.

Is this normal? Or is it an error? I expected that the mask image is just input data and will not be modified in template match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you found a bug in OpenCV...
The type of mask argument is `InputArray`, and it is undocumented that mask may be modified by `matchTemplate`.

OpenCV is an Open Source software, so we can follow the source code (I am using version 4.7.0).

We can find the issue in the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.7.0/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp):
Source file: `sources/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp`
Function: `static void matchTemplateMask( InputArray _img, InputArray _templ, OutputArray _result, int method, InputArray _mask )`.

Source code lines:

```c++
Mat img = _img.getMat(), templ = _templ.getMat(), mask = _mask.getMat();

if (mask.depth() == CV_8U)
{
    // To keep compatibility to other masks in OpenCV: CV_8U masks are binary masks
    threshold(mask, mask, 0/*threshold*/, 1.0/*maxVal*/, THRESH_BINARY);
    mask.convertTo(mask, CV_32F);
}
```

As you can see, the **threshold** function modifies the `mask` matrix.
The original `255` values are converted to `1` after thresholding.

The `threshold` code (bug) was inserted in OpenCV version 4.4.

---

As a workaround, we may save `msk*255`: `imwrite("msk-after.png", msk*255);`
We may also copy the original `msk` to a temporary mask before executing `matchTemplate`.